# Web API CreateAtRoute method errors out

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following post method in my Web API:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostOrderItem(MyClass.OrderItem ordItm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {

        db.OrderItems.Add(ordItem);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("OrderItemApi", new { id = orditm.ItemID, id2 = orditm.ItemVersionID, id3 = ordItm.OrderID }, ordItem);

    }
}
```

My `OrderItemApi` route as follows:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "OrderItemApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 = RouteParameter.Optional, id3 = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

and my `OrderItem` class is:

```
 [Table("SN_OrderItems")]
public class OrderItem
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1), Key]
    public int ItemVersionID { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 2), Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string ItemNote { get; set; }
    public int ItemSortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The above controller method works fine, it does what is expected - adds an item to an `OrderItem` table, but then it errors out on the line:

> return CreatedAtRoute("OrderItemApi", new { id = ordItm.ItemID, id2 = ordItm.ItemVersionID, id3 = ordItm.OrderID }, ordItem);

My question is what am I doing wrong there?  How should I modify the method?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: 500 internal server error, but that is what I get for ANY web api error

Comment: you'll need to surround your action's code with a try/catch.  But also, I noticed you arent defining id3 in your route template.  I use attribute routing, so i cant tell you if thats required or not.

Comment: @Mike_G, defining id3 did not change anything

Comment: @Mike_G, if I wrap my code in try/catch, how do i return the exception to the caller?

Comment: You don't really want to give the caller lots of info for all sorts of reasons. Might be a good idea to log the exception locally.

Comment: Well, at this point I want to do that for debgging purposes for myself. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the error! The issue was that one of the fields - ItemNote was a required field

Comment: for future reference, if you want to return more info, try implementing an exception filter.  Also check your browser's request log, depending on your setup, you may get a 500 error, but looking at the complete request will show the exception error/message.

Answer (score 0):

Had a go at running it on mine and the only fix I found it needed to get it working was from this:

```
        `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}"`
```

to this:

```
        `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}"`
```

Although id3 is not included in your `routeTemplate` and you set it optional, you are actually using it as one of your `routeValues` in `CreatedAtRoute`.

If this doesn't resolve things you might want to consider an exception filter: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling.

Comment: Hmm worked for me and given it's a 500 error I would be looking at an errors with the model/db. Can you debug and get some additional info? Or a try/catch like Mike suggested.

Comment: how do I go about returning the exception from my method?  HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostOrderItem(MyClass.OrderItem ordItm)
{
    try {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
     using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
     {
 
         db.OrderItems.Add(ordItem);
         db.SaveChanges();
 } return CreatedAtRoute("OrderItemApi", new { id = orditm.ItemID, id2 = orditm.ItemVersionID, id3 = ordItm.OrderID }, ordItem);

    }catch(Exception ex){
             ????
    }
}

Comment: How about for now you go to Debug->Windows->Show Diagnostics Tools in Visual Studio. Then when debugging you should see all the exceptions being thrown. Or if you are giving the try/catch a go and you don't have logging in place, put: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message} with stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}");` in the catch and it will show in the VS Output window.

Comment: But what I want is to call Web API via browser and be able to see all exceptions thrown

Comment: Yer so log / look at them locally you really shouldn't be sharing the exceptions they're for you not client.